# SQL - как реализовать аналог вложенного цикла?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, запрос, select

Есть таблица:

**Таблица 1.**

```
"пользователь" "город"

"Маша"         "Москва"

"Маша"         "Лондон"

"Маша"         "Нью-Йорк"

"Петя"         "Нью-Йорк"

"Петя"         "Мюнхен"

"Петя"         "Сан-Франциско"

"Юля"          "Санкт-Петербург"
```

Нужно проверить общие города для каждого пользователя, и вывести количество совпадений, то есть как-то так:

**Таблица 2.**

```
"пользователь 1" "пользователь 2" "Кол-во общ. городов"

"Маша"           "Петя"                  1
"Маша"           "Юля"                   0
"Петя"           "Маша"                  1
"Петя"           "Юля"                   0
"Юля"            "Маша"                  0
"Юля"            "Петя"                  0
```

Я упростил задачу, посчитав, что есть таблица с "Машей" и таблица с "Петей", и нужно найти количество общих городов, получилось что-то вроде:

**Запрос 1.**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
  SELECT m.city FROM masha_table AS m
  INNER JOIN petya_table p ON m.city = p.city
) AS res
```

Данный запрос возвращает верный результат для двух таблиц ("masha_table" и "petya_table ")

Это просто. Однако хотелось бы получить таблицу 2 из таблицы 1.

Думаю, что нужно из Таблицы 1 получить подтаблицу сначала с Машей и остальными пользователями (для каждого по подтаблице), потом с Петей и остальными пользователями и т.д. и свести решение этих подзадач к Запросу 1.

Вопрос: как это можно сделать? В программировании это два вложенных цикла, а тут не соображу никак...

Буду благодарен за помощь :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В SQL `JOIN` без указания условия соединения перемножает таблицы, т.е. перебирает все варианты перестановок. Однако сравнивать Машу с Машей нам не надо, так что мы зададим условие, что пользователи не равны. А вот города в условиях соединения мы сравнивать не будем, т.к. нам нужны записи с нулями. Города мы сравним уже после объединения. В MySQL простой оператор сравнения (`=` ) возвращает 0 или 1 в зависимости от ложности/истинности условия. Нам остается только суммировать 1 ...

```
select a.user, b.user, sum(a.city=b.city)
  from usct a
  join usct b on a.user!=b.user
 group by a.user, b.user
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3ca29/1)

Comment: Спасибо! 
Не знал про то, как работает равенство